# acessing Json Data

Tags: json, api, object, syntax

So im finding it difficult to figure out how to access data from this json file that i got from rapid API.

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "402.8100",
        "03. high": "428.0000",
        "04. low": "372.0201",
        "05. price": "418.3200",
        "06. volume": "110321885",
        "07. latest trading day": "2020-09-04",
        "08. previous close": "407.0000",
        "09. change": "11.3200",
        "10. change percent": "2.7813%"
    }
}
```

When a file is like this, I know it would be Array.Items.type etc.... but what happens when the object is set out like the one above?

```
[Items:{
  type: 1,
  name: "shirt",
  },
  {
  type: 2,
  name: "pants"
  }    
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a nested object within the outer object.

Because the keys contain space, you cannot traverse it using the dot notation (`obj.key.subkey`). You should use square brackets instead (`obj[key][subkey]`).

So to get the `price` info for example you need this:

```
data['Global Quote']['05. price'] // you would get "418.3200"
```

As another example, you get the `symbol` like so:

```
data['Global Quote']['01. symbol'] // you would get "TSLA"
```

The examples start with `data` assuming the whole object is in a variable named data. Like this:

```
var data = {
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "402.8100",
        ...
```

Comment: @KachiCheong you're welcome! This is all Stackoverflow is for.